# Unable to start GUI app from upstart

Tags: upstart

As part of post-start of my app say "mydaemon", I want to launch a GUI app say "mygui". I am unable to do this.

I have verified user perm using `xhost`, `DISPLAY` variable is set correctly. conf file in `/etc/init/` is given below

`$ cat /etc/init/agentd.conf`

```
description  "my daemon"
author       "me"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

console output
kill timeout 60
respawn
respawn limit 3 15

# Allow some clean up time
post-stop script
   env DISPLAY=:0.0
   cd /home/me
   ./mygui
  sleep 1
end script

script
    cd /home/me
    ./myapp
end script

post-start script
   env DISPLAY=:0.0
   cd /home/me
   ./mygui
end script
```

Any suggestions?

xserver is up and running before this script is run. I explicitly started the service myapp after verifying lightdm. I also made the suggested changes to the script however the gui doesn't seen to come up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the "env DISPLAY=:0.0" within the script section, put it outside. Then change the script sections to

```
post-start exec /home/me/mygui
post-stop exec /home/me/mygui
```

You may also want to change from script {...} to

```
exec /home/me/myapp
```

The other problem I can see is that the x server has not started when you try to start your GUI. I am not too sure how to fix that.